# How to use Hash values in ruby

Tags: ruby

I wrote a small Ruby program, but  can't access the hash value stored in the parent class.

Here is the code:

```
class College
  @@dep = ["cs" => 60000, "mat" => 20000, "che" => 30000]
end

class Student < College
  def get_det
    puts "Enter name... \n"
    @name = gets
    puts "Enter department...\n"
    @dpt = gets
  end

  def set_fee
    case @dpt
    when "cs"
      @fee = (@@dep["cs"]).to_i
    when "mat"
      @fee = @@dep["mat"].to_i
    when "che"
      @fee = @@dep["che"].to_i
    else
      puts "Eror!!!"
    end
  end

  def print_det
    puts "Name : #{@name}"
    puts "Department : #{@dpt}"
    puts "Course fee : #{@fee}"
  end
end

det = Student.new

det.get_det
det.set_fee
det.print_det
```

I got the output as:

[Output:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYDY3.png)

Comment: You want `@name = gets.chomp` and `@dpt = gets.chomp`. If the user enters `"Bubba"`, followed by return, `gets` returns `"Bubba\n"`. `chomp` lops off the `"\n"`. If you don't `chomp`, `@dpt` will never be matched in the case statement.

Comment: `gets` will also preserve the new line, so use `String#chomp` as @Cary suggested. Also the `Sudent#set_fee` can be simplified to `@@dep[@dpt].to_i`. Your hierarchy is weird.

Comment: Don't use a link to store a page showing your output. Links rot then break. Instead put the output into the text of your question. Read "[ask]" and "[mcve]".

Answer (score 2):

You've defined your `@@dep` variable as an array, not as a hash. You need to replace `[ ]` with `{ }`, like so:

```
@@dep = {"cs" => 60000, "mat" => 20000, "che" => 30000}
```

Then you'll be able to access your hash values via the string keys:

```
@@dep['cs']  # Will return 6000
```

And just an FYI, your `set_fee` method could be refactored to just be this:

```
def set_fee
  @fee = @@dep[@dpt] || 'Error!'
  puts @fee
end
```

Since you're simply passing in the value you're checking against for each of your `when` statements, you can just pass the value directly to your `@@dep` object. And you don't need `to_i`, because the values in your hash are already integers.